# C# library for exploring Bitcoin Cash blockchain

Tags: client, api, bitcoin-cash, c#

Does anyone know of a good C# library which would enable me to explore the Bitcoin Cash blockchain by communicating with my own node?

Something like Nethereum (Web3) for Ethereum.

Or, alternatively, a third-party API provider, like BlockCypher for Bitcoin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since "Bitcoin Cash" is a fork of Bitcoin Core, you should be able to use the [BitcoinLib](https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib) C# Library to interact with a Bitcoin Cash node.

Comment: Do I need to be running a full node on my machine for this? I want to communicate with a remote node.

Comment: No, you'll just need to configure the library to connect to the remote node using the remote node's IP address. Look at the Configuration section of the README and the `Bitcoin_DaemonUrl` key. Replace "localhost" with the IP address.